# Horizontal scrolling and alternate-line background colors

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am experiencing errors when loading an html/css file. Here are the contents of the file:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    a bunch of tr/td ...
  </table>
</div>
```

---

```
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #00008B;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I see two errors: First, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear. Second, the even-numbered lines are the same background color as the odd-numbered lines. This behavior is consistent between IE 11 and Chrome 69.

What have I done wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix a couple of things:

- On the `table` element, you can try setting it to `display:inline-table;` so that the width of the table won't be limited by the parent container. Add `min-width:100%;` if needed, and remove `width:100%;` to let it grow.
- For the alternate background colors, for rows, apply `tr:nth-child(even) {...}` or `tr:nth-child(even) td {...}`; for columns, use `td:nth-child(even) {...}`
- If you also have `thead` and/or `tfoot` and you only want to apply the colors to `tbody`, makes use to add `tbody tr:nth-child(even)` etc.

In addition:

You don't have to use `<table>`, other options:

- Flexbox: `.container {display:inline-flex;}`
- Inline-blocks: `.container {white-space:nowrap;} .item {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; white-space:normal;}`
- CSS table: `.container {display:inline-table;} .item {display:table-cell;}`.

Of course, either way you choose, keep the wrapper `<div style="overflow-x:auto;">` there as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But it still doesn't work. See the edit that I made to the original question.

Comment: Which part, scrolling? Perhaps the there isn't enough data in the table cells.

Comment: Neither the scrolling nor the alternate background colors work. There are sufficient columns in the table that horizontal scrolling is necessary.

Comment: Ah! I spelled inline-table wrong in my code (but not in the edit I made above). So that is now working. But alternate background colors still don't work.

Comment: Do you want the different colors to apply to rows or columns?

Comment: I want alternate rows to be different colors. I found the definition of "striped tables" at [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) and used that in my original code.

Comment: Can you define what didn't work exactly, does my updated answer help 3rd bullet point?

Comment: I do not use thead or tfoor or tbody. I have tr:nth-chold(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2; }, and also with td before the braces, but neither version gives me rows with alternating background colors.

Comment: Even you don't use `tbody` it will be added automatically, but it doesn't matter in the case.

Comment: However it seems there is a typo in there `tr:nth-chold(even)`.

Comment: The typo is in the comment. The code on my web page is correct.

Comment: What does it say when you Inspect the rows, is there any other css interfering?

Comment: It works at [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyGZYb](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyGZYb) but not in my IE11 browser. Is there some browser setting that I need to change?

Comment: I fixed some line endings; here is a better version: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyGZYb](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyGZYb).

Comment: My weekend is starting. I'll pick this up on Monday morning. In the meantime I accepted your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your demo works fine in IE11, as said you probably have other css is interfering.